# Deny access if the client is using a different SSL certificate

Tags: apache-flex, ssl, https, security

I have scoured this forum the best I could but found no plausible answer, google was no help either.

I have a FLEX 3 application using AMFPHP over HTTPS (Flex RemoteObject). I would like to prevent the client from making any HTTPS requests if the browser client SSL cert is not the one provided by my server, thus making it more difficult for Charles, Burp, etc. to read the data going to the server by proxying the connection.

When someone uses one of these proxy server there is a certificate error as i.e. Charles provides its own cert to the browser and makes the HTTPS connection to the server as a normal client, so on the server end there is no difference.

Is there any way to only allow connections if my cert is the one being used at the client?

Comment: I doubt there is anything you can do.  I have to wonder why this is important, though.

Comment: Users are generally not to careful about just clicking through error messages, even cert warnings. I want to make sure that if someone is exposed to a man-in-the-middle attack that the application stops if it is "forced" to use an alternate certificate.

Comment: Out of curiosity; what type of application are you building that the benefits of such a strict level of security does not outweigh the cost of building it?  I wonder if you can make use of this class to validate the certificate? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html

Comment: Nothing really strict or costly about it. We've taken the standard approach to security - https, session based validation, failed validation lockout, etc. My question is simply if we can stop the user from making a dangerous choice of allowing a foreign cert which in this case either means they are running a local HTTPS proxy and sniffing traffic or someone else is intercepting their traffic, both of which we want to avoid if possible.

Comment: SecureSockets looks very promising. I'll have a go with that.

Comment: If you get it working; be sure to come back and formally answer the question with what you did and how you did it.

Comment: Sorry for the beginner question, but how do I mark your SecureSockets comment as the "answer" ?

Comment: I didn't provide a formal answer; I only commented.  It looks like the answer you provided to the question is much more detailed than anything I could have provided.  You should mark your own answer as the correct one. You should see a "Green Checkbox" or something similar to the left of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using SecureSockets (needed to upgrade to SDK 4.6) I was able to check the validity of the SSL certificate the browser was using.

The default behavior is that any incorrect cert (analog to the browser cert warning) will cause SecureSockets to fail. This makes creating a check very easy using the sample code in the Adobe documentation:

```
private var secureSocket:SecureSocket = new SecureSocket();

    public function SecureSocketExample()
    {
        secureSocket.addEventListener( Event.CONNECT, onConnect )
        secureSocket.addEventListener( IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError );

        try
        {
            secureSocket.connect( "ip address here", 443 );
        }
        catch ( error:Error )
        {
            trace ( error.toString() );
        }
    }
```

[Doc is here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Adding this to the creationComplete listener is enough to make sure the user hasn't followed an insecure cert or man in the middle. The rest of the application's communication can occur over "normal" SSL AMF channel.

Answer (score 1):

One generic approach could be to use [Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Comment: That seems like a very plausible solution when all browser makers get their act together. Looks like IE is behind the curve...
Q: if a man-in-the-middle attack was forwarding this request, could the Strict-Transport-Security header be removed?

Comment: @SalvatoreGiacinto - STS enabled browsers keep a local cache of STS enabled domains until TTL expires so even if attacker removes STS header browser will complain about SSL mismatch. Needless to say, if attacker is poisoning the network even before browser has ever seen the header, STS won't help

Comment: Yes, I understand. It will be a great addition when the powers that be finally get around to supporting it.